# Laravel eloquent where current status is equals to string

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a candidate and a status table which every candidate have multiple statuses. when statuses changes new row in statuses table will be created to store new status. So when user wants to filter candidates by status I want to select candidates that their current status is what user select not the all before statuses.
my query is :

```
 $status = $request->get('status');

        $q->where(function ($q) use ($status) {
            $q->orWhereHas('statuses', function ($q) use ($status) {
                $q->where('status', 'like', "%" . $status . "%");
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the query to the blow and it's working fine.

```
$q->whereRaw('status LIKE "%'.$status.'%" AND id=(select max(id) from statuses WHERE status LIKE "%'.$status.'%")');
```

**EDIT:**

The query in above has a problem and that is it's only get's first matching candidate not all of them so I changed the query to this:

```
  $q->where(function ($q) use ($status) {
            $q->orWhereHas('statuses', function ($q) use ($status) {
                $q->whereRaw('status LIKE ? AND id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM statuses GROUP BY candidate_id)',["%".$status."%"]);
            });
        });
```

Comment: This is how SQL injection happens.

Comment: I know that but status not retrieved directly from user.

Answer (score -1):

my percipience is, current status of a candidate is last record.
i say mysql direction, as for your migrate and modeling, implement this.

```
select * from status 
where id =(
    select max(id) from status 
    where candidate_id= x 
    )
```

x is candidate id.